# Not able to run cmd in foreground using Tomcat as service

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, cmd, foreground

When I am running Tomcat using `statup.bat` and running my `xxx.bat` file I am able to see the `xxx.bat` file running and it is invoking `testNg` and I can see all the test case running.

But when I run Tomcat as service, my `xxx.bat` file start doing its job and start executing the test cases but it run in background.

Problem is I want to see the test case running in foreground.

My code is

```
String batPath = "D:\\Workspaces\\TestingWorkspace\\myproject\\runTestNg.bat";

String pojectRoot  = "D:\Workspaces\TestingWorkspace\myproject";

String path = "cmd /c start " + batPath + " " + projectRoot;

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);

p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read streams from process. There was 3 streams if i remember it right. There was Error stream, Input and output streams. You need to get them, read them and print.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: My problem is not this. My batch file is running and doing its job as it should do but it is doing it in background. and i am not able to see it.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but logs(aka streams) are not handled. Because you don't open cmd in window, there is nothing to show "messages". So you need to implement this when you need to watch them with start. You can see log files in tomcatfolder\logs\localhost***.log, but this is manual stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use word **start** in your cmd command and after that follow the chilltouch advice about reading streams.